# Get the Outer XML inside Power automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate, xml, xpath

I am converting a Nintex flow into Power Automate flow, where inside the Nintex we have this extract XML step;-

[image]

For getting the outer xml and store it inside a Collection, our xml has this format:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RepeaterData><Version /><Items><Item><ArticleInput type="System.String">681495008421</ArticleInput><ArticleDescription type="System.String">KOBO LIBRA 2 EREADER BLK</ArticleDescription><ArticleReturnable type="System.String">True</ArticleReturnable><Qty type="System.Double">1</Qty></Item><Item><ArticleInput type="System.String">681495008421</ArticleInput><ArticleDescription type="System.String">KOBO LIBRA 2 EREADER BLK</ArticleDescription><ArticleReturnable type="System.String">True</ArticleReturnable><Qty type="System.Double">1</Qty></Item></Items></RepeaterData>
```

so what are the available actions inside Power Automate to achieve this?Thanks

Now i tried to initialize a variable as follow:-
[image]

but i got this value for the variable on runtime:-

```
cotent-type":"application/xml;charset=utf-8","$content":"PEl0ZW0+DQogIDxBcnRpY2xlSW5wdXQgdHlwZT0iU3lzdGVtLlN0cmluZyI+MzMzMzMzMzM8L0FydGljbGVJbnB1dD4NCiAgPEFydGljbGVEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiB0eXBlPSJTeXN0ZW0uU3RyaW5nIj5kZXNjMzMzMzM8L0FydGljbGVEZXNjcmlwdGlvbj4NCiAgPEFydGljbGVSZXR1cm5hYmxlIHR5cGU9IlN5c3RlbS5TdHJpbmciPllFUzwvQXJ0aWNsZVJldHVybmFibGU+DQogIDxRdHk
```

any advice on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use below steps to get the outer / inner property of xml payload.

1. Convert Xml to JSON by using below expression in power automate

```
json(xml(outputs('Compose_XML_Payload')))
```

[image: xml payload and xml to json]

2. After conversions parse it in JSON so that you retrieve the property of object.

[image: Parse Json]

- Out Put:

[image: Power Automate]
[image: Power Automat Run]

- RepeaterData output

```
{
    "Version": null,
    "Items": {
        "Item": [
            {
                "ArticleInput": {
                    "@type": "System.String",
                    "#text": "681495008421"
                },
                "ArticleDescription": {
                    "@type": "System.String",
                    "#text": "KOBO LIBRA 2 EREADER BLK"
                },
                "ArticleReturnable": {
                    "@type": "System.String",
                    "#text": "True"
                },
                "Qty": {
                    "@type": "System.Double",
                    "#text": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "ArticleInput": {
                    "@type": "System.String",
                    "#text": "681495008421"
                },
                "ArticleDescription": {
                    "@type": "System.String",
                    "#text": "KOBO LIBRA 2 EREADER BLK"
                },
                "ArticleReturnable": {
                    "@type": "System.String",
                    "#text": "True"
                },
                "Qty": {
                    "@type": "System.Double",
                    "#text": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the helpful reply,, but what i should include in the first Compose action ? thanks

Comment: Don't use first compose action in your power automate. I used it for demo purpose. Pass out put of "Get Article xml"  in second compose i.e. convert xml to JSON.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305125/get-value-from-http-response-xml-and-pass-it-as-a-field-in-next-http-request-fie having same issue