# Get value from http response xml and pass it as a field in next http request field or save it in a variable power automate

Tags: power-automate, xml

how to Get value from http response xml and pass it as a field in next http request field or save it in a variable power automate
MY flow
[image]

Response i get is in xml as below
[image]

response what i get as xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://qualysapi.qg3.apps.qualys.com/qps/xsd/3.0/was/webappauthrecord.xsd">
  <responseCode>SUCCESS</responseCode>
  <count>1</count>
  <data>
    <WebAppAuthRecord>
      <id>981337</id>
      <name><![CDATA[update1TEST]]></name>
      <owner>
        <id>266</id>
        <username>test</username>
        <firstName><![CDATA[API]]></firstName>
        <lastName><![CDATA[test]]></lastName>
      </owner>
      <formRecord>
        <type>STANDARD</type>
        <sslOnly>true</sslOnly>
        <authVault>false</authVault>
        <seleniumCreds>false</seleniumCreds>
        <fields>
          <count>2</count>
          <list>
            <WebAppAuthFormRecordField>
              <id>1006189</id>
              <name><![CDATA[username]]></name>
              <value><![CDATA[john]]></value>
            </WebAppAuthFormRecordField>
            <WebAppAuthFormRecordField>
              <id>1006190</id>
              <name><![CDATA[password]]></name>
              <value><![CDATA[*****]]></value>
            </WebAppAuthFormRecordField>
          </list>
        </fields>
      </formRecord>
      <tags>
        <count>1</count>
        <list>
          <Tag>
            <id>36715192</id>
            <name><![CDATA[app_automation]]></name>
          </Tag>
        </list>
      </tags>
      <comments>
        <count>1</count>
        <list>
          <Comment>
            <contents><![CDATA[some comments]]></contents>
            <createdDate>2022-12-03T06:47:19Z</createdDate>
          </Comment>
        </list>
      </comments>
      <createdDate>2022-12-03T06:47:19Z</createdDate>
      <createdBy>
        <id>26608662</id>
        <username>test</username>
        <firstName><![CDATA[API]]></firstName>
        <lastName><![CDATA[th]]></lastName>
      </createdBy>
      <updatedDate>2022-12-03T06:47:19Z</updatedDate>
      <updatedBy>
        <id>26608662</id>
        <username>test</username>
        <firstName><![CDATA[API]]></firstName>
        <lastName><![CDATA[th]]></lastName>
      </updatedBy>
    </WebAppAuthRecord>
  </data>
</ServiceResponse>
```

Tied below:
[image]

Is there a way to get the value 981337 as variable which can be passed to next http request.

Tried below as well based on inputs but fails
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only missed to use "**text()**" function to get node value. Try below XPath and it should work:

```
/ServiceResponse/data/WebAppAuthRecord/id/text()
```

Make sure that above will return result as array even if we have single node in XML so while using it make sure that you use as below:

```
outputs('{Your Compose Action Name}')?[0]
```

[image]

Flow Output:

[image]

Comment: Added the same in question but fails can you help what could be the issue bit new to power automate.

Comment: Thanks that worked.